How to Handle Multiple Batch in Single File In EDI Using Biztalk?
I have Successfully Load EDI file using Biztalk but it handle Single Batch it time but now i need to Load Multiple Batch in Single Batch File here is my Orchestration so can any help into it to load multiple batch in single file because currently it is throw error Deadlock error due to call in single File.

